# Dell E6320 laptop not detecting external hard disk

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Dell laptop model E6320. The laptop does not detect an external hard disk (Transcend hard disk 320 GB).

When I connect my hard disk to the laptop, the blue light on the drive blinks but it is not reading the contents of the harddisk.

Comment: The driver should not be installed.. 
- Right CLick computer Select Properties>Device Manager>Disconnect Your Device> Connect> Click Refresh >Expand USB> See if the drive is displayed as unknown drive> Right Click the USB Drive > Click Update Driver